# Visual studio gives multiple errors when I try to compile C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

int aNumber; 
printf( "Enter a number:"); 
scanf( "%d", &aNumber); 
printf( "You entered %d", aNumber ); 
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Hey I'm really new to coding and was trying to compile a simple C program using Visual Studio Express. I know for sure there is no syntax error with this code but it persists in giving me errors.

> Error 4 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'return'
>
> Warning 3 warning C4024: 'printf' : different types for formal and
>   actual parameter 1
>
> Warning 1  warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or
>   variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable
>   deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.  See online help for
>   details.
>
> Warning 2 warning  C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs
>   in levels of indirection from 'int'
>
> Warning 3 warning  C4024: 'printf'
>   : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

I don't understand the issue.

Comment: You know for sure? The evidence is against you if the compiler rejects the code! The compiler error messages tell you what is wrong; to bad you did not give us that benefit. Nonetheless, the stray character after `{` is probably the cause. When you do get this to compile, be aware that `getchar()` will return immediately because your `scanf()` call does not consume the newline.

Comment: Also this code, might compile fine but it has a potential bug, because you discard `scanf()`'s return value. And AFAIK `scanf()` should be replaced by `scanf_s()` when using MSVC compiler or it will trigger a Secure C Runtime warning I think.

Comment: for readability by us humans, Please indent code consistently.  never use tabs for indenting as each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  in general: intent after every opening brace. `{`  un-indent before every closing brace. `}`  It also helps readability to separate code blocks (if, else, do...while, while, for, switch, case, default) by a blank line

Comment: suggest prefix your program with `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`  to eliminate the security warnings such as requesting `scanf_s()` rather than `scanf()`

Comment: @AlexanderTrust 
Yes that is by coincidence while I was trying to format my post for here.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi here are the errors as they appear
Error 4 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'return' 
Warning 3 warning C4024: 'printf' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1 
Warning 1 warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. 
Warning 2 warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int' 
Warning 3 warning C4024: 'printf' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

Comment: @user3629249 I tried using that. All of the warnings persist. The code works fine when use the Native Tools Command Prompt to compile

Comment: @AliYaqoob This code (if I remove that ` ` ` ), does not throw any compiler error (atleast on my VS2008)

Comment: @GNKeshava the code works fine using native tools command prompt. It's just the visual express giving me [errors](http://imgur.com/Lab8wD3)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add pre-processor `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in project property in release and debug mode as you see in image then will done.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide complete error list windows ? Because I am not able to see left and right part in what you provided.

Comment: it's not giving me any error, I think create new project with help of http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/tali/E15/Visual_C.html

Comment: From image i understand you are having two file and all this error in 1.c.  not in what code you have given from 2.c . check your other file or remove it .